# Mocking static methods in Java without annotations

Tags: java, testing, clojure, mocking

Are there any libraries for the JVM that allow mocking of static methods WITHOUT needing annotations?  I am attempting to build this feature into a Clojure testing framework (Midje).  Clojure has very poor, or non-existant annotation support.

Answer (score 3):

Use [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).It's a great library for mocking. And [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) is an example that explains how to mock static methods.

Comment: looks like PowerMock requires annotations.